# Unprotected Private Key File for AWS EC2 SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

This question has been asked so many times that I am embarrassed to ask it. I  have read through the other responses with no success.

I keep getting the following error messages after using these commands:

```
cd desktop\putty\webserver

chmod 400 webserver.pem   

ssh -i "webserver.pem" ec2-user@ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com


 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    Permissions for 'webserver.pem' are too open.
    It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
    This private key will be ignored.
    Load key "webserver.pem": bad permissions
    ec2-user@ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Common response to this issue has been to use the `chmod 400 webserver.pem`   command. I have also tried the `chmod 600` command. Other responses has been to right click on the .pem file and change permissions. I have done those already but still not success.

Comment: Are you using ssh on windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 10 trying to connect to an ec2 instance.

Comment: Is chmod 400 for windows 10? Just asking, I don't know. chmod is for linux, does w10 support it?

Comment: I installed Git which I believe allows me to run chmod. Also I have downloaded an installed OpenSSH from here https://www.openssh.com/. The chmod works with no errors. But initially it was not recognized until I installed openssh.

Comment: The key permission may also indicate incorrect permissons on the folder containing it. I'm not too familiar with how it works on windows, but you have to check some resources on how to set these permissions correctly.

Comment: Have a look at this Superuser answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open

Comment: @Traub I already looked at that but doing it a second time I figured it out. In my 'Groups or Usernames' I have a username called 'Everyone'. I removed that group along with others and I gave myself all permissions to read/write on the .pem file. Thank you for the suggestion.